# JavaFX Confirmation Alert will not open

Tags: javafx

I am trying to create an Inventory Management program, and I need to open a confirmation dialog when a user presses a cancel button. All of the examples seem pretty straightforward, however my Alert does not open.

AddPartController.java
(I promise this is not where the import statements are at)

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Optional;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Alert;
import javafx.scene.control.Alert.AlertType;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.ButtonType;
import javafx.scene.control.RadioButton;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

@FXML
private Button addPartCancelBtn;

@FXML
void addPartCancelBtnHandler(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {

    Alert alert = new Alert(AlertType.CONFIRMATION);
    alert.setTitle("Cancel Add Part");
    alert.setHeaderText("This part will not be added");
    alert.setContentText("Are you ok with this?");
    Optional<ButtonType> result = alert.showAndWait();
    if(result.isPresent() && result.get() == ButtonType.OK) {
        Stage stage;
        Parent root;
        stage = (Stage) addPartCancelBtn.getScene().getWindow();
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("Main.fxml"));
        root = loader.load();
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
        System.out.println("OK PRESSED");
     } else {
        Stage stage;
        Parent root;
        stage = (Stage) addPartCancelBtn.getScene().getWindow();
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("AddPart.fxml"));
        root = loader.load();
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
        System.out.println("Errror");
    }
}
```

Can anyone see an issue here?

Comment: Personally, I'm unable to see the problem from what you've given us. Try to create a [mcve].

Comment: Are you catching the IOException?

Comment: Are you sure the alert isn't showing, or is it behind the stage? Also, are you certain that method is being triggered? I'd add a print statement to make sure its actually being called, then work from there.

Comment: @Sedrick, at the moment no, I will try surrounding with a try catch

Comment: @HypnicJerk, I can't see how it isn't being triggered. addPartCancelBtnHandler is the only action that I specified for that button, I'll keep looking.

Comment: Thank you @Sedrick, the try-catch block fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a Try Catch block fixed it:

```
@FXML
void addPartCancelBtnHandler(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {
    try {
        Alert alert = new Alert(AlertType.CONFIRMATION);
    alert.setTitle("Cancel Add Part");
    alert.setHeaderText("This part will not be added");
    alert.setContentText("Are you ok with this?");
    alert.getDialogPane().setPrefSize(350, 200);
    Optional<ButtonType> result = alert.showAndWait();
    if(result.isPresent() && result.get() == ButtonType.OK) {
        Stage stage;
        Parent root;
        stage = (Stage) addPartCancelBtn.getScene().getWindow();
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("Main.fxml"));
        root = loader.load();
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
        System.out.println("OK PRESSED");
     } else {
        Stage stage;
        Parent root;
        stage = (Stage) addPartCancelBtn.getScene().getWindow();
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("AddPart.fxml"));
        root = loader.load();
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
        System.out.println("Errror");
    }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```